# How to Apply Negative Margin or Class in Jquery error placement?

Tags: jquery, css

```
    $("#frmNewList").validate({
    rules:{
    price:{
                        required: true, 
                        number: true
                          }
          },
    messages: {
    price:{ 
                        required: "Please Enter The Price",
                        number: "Please Enter the amount only"
                         }
              },
    errorPlacement:function(f,g){
             if(g.attr('id')=='price')
              {
                f.addClass('margin');
                f.css({'margin-left':'-10px !important'});
             }

    });
<style>
.margin{margin-left:-10px !important;
}
</style>
```

Here i have two questions:
    1) I want to apply -10px margin shown in code but it is not working.
    2) I add margin class shown in code.
   Both are added individually. But both are not working.

Comment: What's the error console report? You sure `typeof f`, is an jQuery object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!important` doesn't works with JQuery css

Change your code

```
f.css({'margin-left':'-10px !important'});
```

to

```
f.css({'margin-left':'-10px'});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BrzM9/1/

Update: Sure you can use `margin-top`

```
$("#div1").css({'margin-left':'-10px', 'margin-top':'-20px'});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hFZs9/3/

Comment: Nice =] Although note to @aliasgar vanak, you're not going to need to use `!important` anyway as it's an inline style. It's got the most authority possible already.

Comment: @MackieeE:Thanks but here is one problem that i could not apply margin_top after using margin_left.

Comment: @Satpal: Thanks man. One problem is that i could not apply Class and also not apply margin_top after using margin_left.

Comment: @SatPal : Thanks again man. I put this code but when i inspect the element it shows me 10px in margin-left not -10 px. And when i set it through the inspect element i get my result.